# Is the event independent?

Tags: probability, negative-binomial-distribution

I wanted to know if this event is independent or not? The question is as follows:

> In monsoon season, what is the probability that we will have a sunny
>   day after a series of rainy days, or the opposite what is the
>   probability of rain in summer after a series of sunny days?

Would it be considered to be an independent event if you have a sunny day after a series of rainy days during the monsoon season. Since seasonal pattern favor a rainy day thus sunny day is an independent event?

Comment: The season would have an impact on the probability of the weather on the day I think. Have they given you any probability values?

Comment: It is not an assignment but a personal project i am coding in python! :)

Comment: @william3031 I wonder would it not be like a double negative, true season would have an impact but we are looking for sunny day during monsoon.